# How to compare 2 sets of different date which contains 2 different sets of data?

Tags: matlab, date, datetime, comparison

I have 2 sets of Date, their 1st and last dates are the same respectively but their dates within might not be the same to each other. Both DateA and DateB contain different values on their each date, which are arrays A and B.

```
DateA=    '2016-01-01'
          '2016-01-02'
          '2016-01-04'
          '2016-01-05'
          '2016-01-06'
          '2016-01-07'
          '2016-01-08'
          '2016-01-09'
          '2016-01-10'
          '2016-01-12'
          '2016-01-13'
          '2016-01-14'
          '2016-01-16'
          '2016-01-17'
          '2016-01-18'
          '2016-01-19'
          '2016-01-20'


DateB=    '2016-01-01'
          '2016-01-02'
          '2016-01-03'
          '2016-01-04'
          '2016-01-05'
          '2016-01-09'
          '2016-01-10'
          '2016-01-11'
          '2016-01-12'
          '2016-01-13'
          '2016-01-15'
          '2016-01-16'
          '2016-01-17'
          '2016-01-19'
          '2016-01-20'

A = [5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 7, 9, 3, 6, 1, 7, 9, 2, 1, 4, 6]

B = [4, 2, 7, 1, 8, 4, 9, 5, 3, 9, 3, 6, 7, 2, 9]
```

I have converted the dates into datenumber,ie

```
datenumberA=    736330
                736331
                736333
                736334
                736335
                736336
                736337
                736338
                736339
                736341
                736342
                736343
                736345
                736346
                736347


datenumberB=    736330
                736331
                736332
                736333
                736334
                736338
                736339
                736340
                736341
                736342
                736344
                736345
                736346
                736348
                736349
```

Now I want to compare the value of A on DateA(n) to that of B on DateB while DateB is the date that is closest to and before the date of DateA(n).

For example,

comparing the value of A on DateA '2016-01-12' to that of B on DateB '2016-01-11'.

Please help and thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by **comparing**? What result are you expecting?

Comment: To see if A is greater than the corresponding B, the result should be 1(greater) or 0(not greater)

Comment: As you wrote: "`DateB` is the date that is closest to and before the date of `DateA(n)`", what should be the result when DateA is `'2016-01-01'`? Since there is no entry in DateB which is closest and before `'2016-01-01'`?

Comment: The first order of DateA does not need to be compared as both DateA's and DataB's first order are the same so that will be the exceptional one. Sorry I did not mention that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It'll get you the desired output!

```
all_k=0;
out(1)=1;    % not comparing the first index as you mentioned
for n=2:size(datenumberA,1)
    j=0;
    while 1
        k=find(datenumberB+j==datenumberA(n)-1); %finding the index of DateB closest to and before DateA(n)
        if size(k,1)==1 break; end %if found, come out of the while loop
        j=j+1;         % otherwise keep adding 1 in the values of datenumberB until found
    end
    if size(find(all_k==k),2) ~=1 % to avoid if any DateB is already compared
        out(end+1)=A(n)> B(k); %Comparing Value in A with corresponding value in B
        all_k(end+1)=k; end %Storing which indices of DateB are already compared
end
out'   %Output
```

**Output:-**

```
ans =

 1
 0
 0
 1
 0
 0
 1
 0
 0
 1
 0
 0
 1
```